# Continue an interrupted git-push (resume upload)

Tags: git, ssh

So I'm doing this pretty huge git-push, about 2 GB of data being pushed to my server. Suddenly my wifi connection dies. So now after transferring over 250 MB over my slow connection, I have to start again, just to risk the whole thing all over.

[/rant]

When doing a git-push to an SSH remote, is there any way to continue the transfer after it failed?

If not, what's the best way to transfer the repository over a flaky connection, while avoiding to have to upload *all* of the files?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the server end will clean up any incomplete object transfers when the connection is closed, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: I would think if it is interrupted, you have to do it from scratch again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rsync your .git directory of your repo to a new directory, say newdir/.git on your server. Then ssh to that server and do a git checkout on any of the branches you have. Then add the local repo that you wanted to push to originally as a remote and do a local push.

As rsync is immune to network interruption you should be able to continue whenever that happens.

Comment: You can copy the existing .git directory on the server to the newdir/.git directory before starting rsync but that might not save you much in term of data that will need to be transferred because of the way git creates packfiles.

Comment: Good idea, but I guess this could be inefficient if the repo is even larger than the push to be done.

Comment: make sure to use rsync -P though, to allow partial transfers.