# Resuming git push

Tags: git, github, resume

I am trying to do a git push to a remote server, for a big project.
Is there any way once the upload is started, that if the connection is lost, I can resume the git push command and not have to start all over again?

edit: I am trying to push to github

edit2:  so it seems that the way to go is doing it incremental. Can somebody put an example on how to do that when I have the full repository already on my computer?

Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if this were automatic; although you could have better results with git-send-pack directly

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326290/continue-an-interrupted-git-push-ssh ?

Comment: Thanks Roberto,  but I am trying to push to github so I dont think rsync is possible

Comment: If this is a recurring problem, as a hacky workaround, you could try pushing incrementally instead - move your branch up a few commits, push, a few more, push...

Comment: Thanks Jefromi,  can you please put your answer with an example?  Thanks

Comment: Incremental pushes aren't necessarily the way to go. What's causing the failures? If you have enormous commits, you might want to solve that problem instead.

Answer (score 9):

Hacky workaround: push several intermediate commits, so that you're not pushing as much each time. This of course won't save you if it's a single enormous commit that's failing to push.

```
# develop, and end up wanting to push master
git branch master-tmp <commit>
git push origin master-tmp:master
git branch -f master-tmp <a more recent commit>
git push origin master-tmp:master
# ...keep going until you've pushed everything you want
```

There are two primary ways to pick the commits to push:

- `master~15`, `master~10`, `master~5` (15, 10, and 5 commits before `master`)
- Use `gitk` to manually find them; when you select a commit in the history, the SHA1 is automatically put in the middle-click paste clipboard.

Answer (score 2):

rsync your .git/objects directory to the remote, then do git push - it will go much faster.

Comment: I believe I cant do that with github

Comment: Great advice, I'll see if I can pull this off: I'm trying to sync a *huge* repo, and I'm not sure if two copies fit no the server at one :P.

Answer (score 2):

incremental git push

```sh
r=remote
b=main # branch
n=$(git rev-list --count $b) # total number of commits
d=1000 # delta. push $d commits per iteration
for i in $(seq $n -$d 0 | tail -n +2)
do
  (set -x; git push $r $b~$i:$b)
done &&
git push $r $b:$b
```