# git, upload big file in unstable connection?

Tags: linux, git

I try to upload some file to `github` with git in linux.
I have a big file and a unstable connection. upload was interrupted many times.
Is there any way to upload these files resumable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git isn't made for big files. Git is version control system for small files of text or code. For big files use [GitLFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/). When you have connections problems you can't solve that in my mind.

Another solution for large files is rsync with append.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in "[Resuming git push](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7844696/6309)", there is no "resume push" in Git, only pushing less and smaller commits.

rsync the `.git/objects` folder [is often advised](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7326919/6309), but is not possible in your case (GitHub).